# How to construct a moebius loop using bezier curves

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

How can I cut 2 bezier circles and then join them to make one continuous loop and then extrude a circle along the loop? Then texture it to make it look like a garden hose like my StackExchange profile picture.

This is not a duplicate. It is a different form of moebius loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you have activated the Add mesh: Extra objects, you can use the XYZ surface to create a shape that looks like your avatar. The parameter you'll want to experiment with in the image below, is the 1.5. It controls the size of the inner loop. The 2 controls the number of loops.
I used the formula for an epicycloid (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicycloid) and modified it slightly, to give it depth.
Once it looks good, convert it to a curve and put a bevel on it.
[image: How to create an epicycloid]

EDIT: I realise that this isn't exactly what you wanted to do, but if you add bars between the loops, it should pretty accurately reproduce the kind of image you want.

Comment: Thanks but I like the adjustability of the bezier curve/circle.

Comment: And there probably is a way to it with them too. But I hate them. Because I'm worthless att manipulating them. No matter how I push, pull and rotate, I always end up with sharp points. This was my solution. I hope you find yours. :) TC

Comment: I think you may be able to do it with only one circle. I couldn't let this go, so I made a quick try just now. Go into edit mode and select a handle point and rotate it 180° around the axis to which the handle is perpendicular. Don't use the control point, because it won't work. If you get the same results I did, you should be able to take it from there, as you're likely better at bézier curves than I am.

Comment: I have a better idea! What about creating a virtual rope and then I can create whatever I want from that. For example, a kline bottle.

Comment: For a kline bottle I would insist that a set of parametric equations is better. And I actually have such a set saved as a preset. I will gladly share it with you, if you're interested.  
  
http://i61.tinypic.com/k3p3ld.png

Comment: That sounds good, thanks. But how do I use them?

Comment: I'll start a new thread later today. I'll explain how to enable and use the XYZ math surface mesh and specifically how to create that kleine bottle. And I'll include the specific equations so you can just cut and paste them.

Comment: I have posted it here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18955/modelling-a-kleine-bottle