# How can I make a hole in a hole in a hole?

Tags: modeling

How can I make  of a hole in a hole in a hole by using *Blender*?

There is an image from this [book.(page 22)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0914098705)

[image]

Comment: You learn basic modeling techniques like extrusion. That's how.

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18955/modelling-a-klein-bottle)  and possibly better images here  http://www.kleinbottle.com/gallery/Hole-through-a-Hole-in-a-Hole

Comment: Given that this is topographically equivalent to a three-holed torus, I wonder if there are any solutions which take advantage of that...

Answer (score 25):

Add a UV Sphere <kbd>SHFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > UV Sphere with 48 Segments and 32 Rings.

[image: UV Sphere]

<kbd>TAB</kbd> into Edit Mode and select 97 verticies on the top and press <kbd>X</kbd> to delete them.

[image: Delete Top]

Select one vertex on the side and press <kbd>X</kbd> to delete it.

[image: Side]

Select the vertices that make up the edge of the newly created hole and press <kbd>SHFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and drag the mouse to round them.

[image: Round]

**EDIT:** I noticed that after add a SubSurf Modifier when I was finished that there was some puckering around the hole on the side. In order to fix this with the newly rounded still selected press <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and Extrude in just slightly.

[image]

Add a default Torus by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> > Torus. Scale it down by pressing <kbd>S</kbd>.

[image: Torus]

Select a vertex on the side of the Torus and press <kbd>X</kbd> to delete it.

[image]

Select the vertices that make up the edge of the newly created hole in the Torus and press <kbd>SHFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and drag the mouse to round them.

[image: Round]

Add the hole in the Sphere to the selection and press <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> type in "Bridge" and select "Bridge Edge Loops.

[image]

Press <kbd>1</kbd> to go into Front View and delete the vretices on the left half and on the bottom half.

[image]

Add a Mirror Modifier check the box next to "Clipping" And <kbd>Z</kbd>

[image: Mirror Modifier]

Select the vertices that make up the edge of the hole at the top of the Sphere and press <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to Extrud them down on the z axis.

[image: Extrude]

[image: WireFrame]

With some Loop Cuts in the shafts and some Proportional Editing and a  Subsurf Modifier and Smooth Shading.

[image]

Answer (score 23):

In Front Ortho View create a circle with 18 vertices, align to view. Use <kbd>F6</kbd> to enter the values. Keep the 3D-Cursor in the center.

[image: circle]

Switch to Edit Mode and delete the right half including top and bottom verts.

[image: half a circle]

Select the new top and bottom verts. Connect them with <kbd>F</kbd> and subdivide the edge, number of cuts: two.

[image: inner hole]

Move the middle verts a bit towards the middle. Select the two leftmost verts, duplicate them. Then extrude along the X axis. Then select the face and remove the face.

[image: ring]

Select everything, go into Top View and use Spin, 10 segments, 360°. 3D-Cursor still in the center?

[image: spin]

Select everything, remove doubles and use <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to cut a narrow corridor out.

[image: clipping border]

Adjust the view, switch to Face Select Mode and Select the two faces shown. <kbd>SPACE</kbd> Bridge Edgeloops.

[image: corridor 1]

Repeat for the other side.

[image: corridor 2]

Get rid of the Clipping Border with <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>, select everything and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals.

[image: normals]

Add a Subsurf Modifier with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> and set the shading to smooth. Adjust the Subsurf to 3 render levels in the modifier settings.

[image: subsurf]

Done.

[image: result]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

1. Sphere
2. Add Cylinder
3. Boolean Modifier on Sphere Difference out the Cylinder >> Then Apply
4. Add Taurus + 2 Cylinders

[image]

5. Boolean Modifier on Taurus (Times 2 - 1 for each cylinder) Difference out each cylinder >> Then Apply
6. Select the faces indicated in step #5 from the image above >> <kbd>X</kbd> >> <kbd>V</kbd>
7. Select ring of vertices at hole >> <kbd>E</kbd> >> 1.00 Then <kbd>S</kbd> >> 0.00 >> <kbd>Enter</kbd> (repeat this step on opposite side).
8. Move Sphere from step #3 over shape from #7.
9. Set Boolean Modifier on Sphere >> Difference out the shape from #7.

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice to see what you have tried so far. 
Anyway I try to give you an idea how it works.

- Crate a UV Sphere.
- Go into Edit Mode and select the point at the top where all the segments meet each other. (Simply the "highest" point on the top of the sphere)
- Delete those vertices and also select and delete the vertices at the bottom of the sphere.
- Select an endge from the top ring and the corresponding edge from the bottom ring and create a face between them by pressing <kbd>F</kbd>. 
  -You can select the edges quite easy if you go to Top-View (Press
  <kbd>NumPad 7</kbd>) and Ortho-View (Press <kbd>NumPad 5</kbd>). Then uncheck "Limit
  section to visible" and use the Box-Select Mode (Press <kbd>B</kbd>) to select
  an edge and the edge directly underneath it.

Now you should already have the vertical hole. 
The process with the horizontal hole is quite similar but you should be able to do it if you watch some Youtube videos on basic modelling.

I hope I could help you.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26207/how-can-i-format-as-keyboard-keys

Comment: @  Ray Mairlot - Thanks! I've been wanting to know how to do that for a long time.